How can I skip the "verify your purchase instantly" screen in Google Play?
Google Play started displaying that screen:

How can I skip it? I don't want to activate it.

It seems to be a sort of advertisement to ask you if you want to "upgrade" to biometric authentication for purchases. If you choose "Use password" it should keep the same behavior and (hopefully) not display the same prompt again.
